# msapplication-task for browsers other than IE?

Tags: html, browser, meta-tags

In IE, using `<META NAME="msapplication-task" CONTENT="name=TASKNAME;action-uri=ONCLICK;icon-uri=ICON" />`, you can easily place a custom-action icon into the jump list of a pinned site using IE 9+ in Windows 8+. **Is there any way to accomplish the same or similar effect with other browsers?**

On this topic, **Is there any way to accomplish this effect in other operating systems?** I'm mainly interested in Max OS 10.6+ and Ubuntu 10.10+ (that is to say, and Ubuntu with Unity)

Answer (score 2):

iOS has *some* of this. Put this in your `<head>`:

```
<!-- Hide the browser UI when pinned to the home screen -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
```

You can set homescreen icons in the root directory. You'll want the following:

```
<!-- With a reflective shine -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">

<!-- Without a reflective shine -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">
```

The [HTML5 Boilerplate recommends](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html#L13) that you just put the icons in the root directory, just like a favicon.

Comment: Awesome! Any knowledge at all of other OSs/browsers? Also, how would a user take advantage of this?

Comment: A user can open a menu and say "Add to homescreen" and then it'll look like an app on their homescreen. I don't know much about other browsers or OSes.